# Using Excel Data Reader Open Source

Tags: c#, .net, excel

Should the MS Excel be installed for working with the open source API Excel Data Reader.(https://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I think that if it did, then they would explicitly state it as a dependency.

Comment: What stops you from trying it?  Try it, before just asking (and waiting for an answer).

Comment: @Styxxy, I have MS office installed in my laptop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says it supports Linux, OS X, BSD with Mono 2+, so Excel needn't be installed.